# Objective-C place object into each array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am a newbie to Objective-C and iOS.

I have a NSMutableArray with 180 objects.They are all sorted.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:180];
for (int i = 0; i < 180; i ++) {
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i+1];
    [array addObject:string];
}
```

Now, I want to put them into a NSArray, which this NSArray is a five-objects Array.(I mean the array contains 5 object each). And I had come up with two method to do so.

### Method 1

```
NSMutableArray *outer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *inner =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
for (id object in array)
{
    int i = 0;
    [inner addObject:object];
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        [outer addObject:inner];
    }
    i ++;
}
NSLog(@"%@",outer);
```

### Method 2

```
NSMutableArray *outer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *inner =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
for (int i = 0; i < 180; i ++)
{
    if (i % 5 == 0 && i != 0) {
        [outer addObjectsFromArray:inner];
        [inner removeAllObjects];
        [inner addObject:array[i]];
    }else{
        [inner addObject:array[i]];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",outer);
```

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are modifying the same object which is inner array over and over and storing it in outer array instead create new inner array every time when limit which is 5 is exhausted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with the first approach, which is simplest.

However, there were a few problems:

i was being set to 0 each time. It needs to be declared outside.

```
NSMutableArray *outer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *inner = nil;
int i = 0;

for (id object in array)
{
    if (inner = nil) {
        inner = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    } 
    [inner addObject:object];
    i ++;
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
        [outer addObject:inner];
        inner = nil;
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSArray *)Addarraydata : (NSMutableArray *) inputArray{

    NSMutableArray * arrNewArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(int i = 0; i < [inputArray count]; i = i + 5){
        if((i + 5) < [inputArray count]){
           [arrNewArray addObject:[inputArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 5)]];
        }else{
            [arrNewArray addObject:[inputArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, ([inputArray count] - i))]];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"arrNewArray = %@",arrNewArray);

    return arrNewArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *outer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < [array count] / 5; i++) {
   [outer addObject:[array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(i*5, 5)]];
}
```

And if array can be a non multiple of 5 and you want to get the rest, you can add this after the for loop :

```
NSUInteger rest = [array count] % 5;
if (rest != 0) {
   [outer addObject:[array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange([array count] / 5 * 5, rest)]];
}
```

Comment: Your for loop is invalid and will never terminate